# while loop: number less than number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first time posting here. Sorry if it's not the correct way. In the following code, there are three loops iterations. I can understand why. But I need it to be only 2. Is there a way to do this?

```
weeks_x = 0
weeks_year = 52

count = 0

while weeks_x < weeks_year:
   weeks_x = weeks_x + 25
   count = count + 1
```

Comment: what output you are expecting here?

Comment: Did you try writing out the value of `weeks_x` for each iteration? This is a good skill to have in general.

Comment: Why not condition the while loop on the counter instead of weeks_x?  Then you can precisely control the number of rounds in the loop. Especially if you know beforehand the exact number of times you plan to run the loop.

Comment: `for _ in range(2):` instead of `while weeks_x < ... :`

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your code with simple `print` statements

```
weeks_x = 0
weeks_year = 52

count = 0

while weeks_x < weeks_year:
   weeks_x = weeks_x + 25
   count = count + 1
   print(f'Iteration Number {count} and weeks_x is {weeks_x}')
```

The output makes it crystal why the loop runs for 3 times

```
Iteration Number 1 and weeks_x is 25
Iteration Number 2 and weeks_x is 50
Iteration Number 3 and weeks_x is 75
```

Since only after the 3rd iteration the value of `weeks_x` is enough to break this condition `weeks_x < 52` it goes for 3 turns

You can limit the number of times the loop runs

```
weeks_x = 0
weeks_year = 52

count = 0

# while weeks_x < weeks_year: # REMOVE THIS
while count < 2: # ADD THIS
   weeks_x = weeks_x + 25
   count = count + 1
   print(f'Iteration Number {count} and weeks_x is {weeks_x}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `print()` statement can be useful in debugging:

```py
weeks_x = 0
weeks_year = 52
count = 0
while weeks_x < weeks_year:
    print('weeks_x:', weeks_x, '- weeks_year', weeks_year)
    weeks_x = weeks_x + 25
    count =+ 1
```

output:

```py
weeks_x: 0 - weeks_year 52
weeks_x: 25 - weeks_year 52
weeks_x: 50 - weeks_year 52
```

If you specifically needed two loop iterations:

```py
weeks_x = 0
weeks_year = 52
count = 0
while count < 2:
    print('weeks_x:', weeks_x, '- weeks_year', weeks_year)
    weeks_x = weeks_x + 25
    count =+ 1
```

`count` variable is counting the number of loops.

Alternatively, `weeks_x * 2` will give the same result as the loop - otherwise if there is functionality that requires this I suggest looking at `for loops` with `range()`.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing before while

```
weeks_x = 0
weeks_year = 52

count = 0

weeks_x += 25
while weeks_x < weeks_year:
  count += 1
  print('Count {}'.format(count), 'Week Value {}'.format(weeks_x), sep='-->', end='\n')
  weeks_x += 25
```

Output:-

```
Count 1-->Week Value 25
Count 2-->Week Value 50
```